# How to split m4b file into many tracks on linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, conversion, codec, audio-conversion

I do have an audiobook with m4b extension, and I wish to split it into many tracks so that it becomes more manageable on my mobile.

Through [splitting m4a into multiple files with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939463/splitting-m4a-into-multiple-files-with-ffmpeg), I successfully splitted m4a files.

My working command is
`ffmpeg -i <filename> -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 1800 -reset_timestamps 1 -c copy "$output%03d.m4a" -c:a aac` which splits into 0.5 hour chunks.

I wish to do the same with my m4b file. I tried to rename it from `.m4a` to `.m4b`, and even though the audio worked on my PC the conversion failed, Showing:

```
[ipod @ 0x555697bea640] Could not find tag for codec mjpeg in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container                                       
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

[image]

Comment: `codec not currently supported in container` - it is clear that an update (new codec?)  is required, I have no idea whether that actually is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rename the file extension of media files because this may confuse ffmpeg.

Probably the most user friendly way of splitting the file to avoid using ffmpeg and having to provide the necessary parameter is to have a look at the utility m4b-tool which was designed as a front end to ffmpeg to process m4b files.

> m4b-tool is a command line utility to merge, split and chapterize audiobook files such as mp3, ogg, flac, m4a or m4b

[sandreas](https://github.com/sandreas) / [**m4b-tool**](https://github.com/sandreas/m4b-tool)